# Pre overflow problem whole body scrolls when overflow instead of only pre element

Tags: css

You may see when some line in pre code is too long when instead of only scrolling that element the scrollbar appears on the whole body and whole body gets scrollable and the pre messes up the whole page as it goes beyond the 100% width. See the red border at the top it denotes the normal 100% of the page.
How to prevent this.
I want scroll bar such that only pre is scrolled not the whole body.

```css
.container-full {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.top-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-header img {
    height: 83vh;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.header-content {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.header-content h1, p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.header-content h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.main-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 40px 8px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    color: #000;
}
.main-btn:hover {
    background: #c86bd6;
}
.btn-text {
    color: #f1020d;
}
.content-inner {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
/* CODE EXAMPLE */
.code-eg-container {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.code-eg-inner {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 410px;
    background: #22015473;
    padding: 13px;
}
.code-eg-header {
    display: block;
}
.code-eg-header a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.tab-pane {
    background: rgba(108,6,166,0.4);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(108,6,166,0.7) 6%, rgba(25,1,153,0.6) 100%);
    border: 0;
}
pre {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-pills li a {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
display: inline-block;
line-height: normal;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 7px 21px 6px 21px;;
text-decoration: none;
background: transparent;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
transition: 0.2s linear;
font-weight: bold;
}

.code-eg-header .nav-pills li.active a {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44 !important;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
}
/* END */

/* MEDIA */
@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .code-eg-container {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .code-eg-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-full">
  <div class="top-header" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  </div>
  <div class="header-wrap">

    <div class="row header-content">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
          </p>
          <a class="main-btn">Let's Try <span class="btn-text">It's Free</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 code-eg-container">

            <div class="code-eg-inner">
              <div class="code-eg-header">
                <ul class="nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">PHP</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#curlsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Curl</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Python</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#rubysample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Ruby</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#javasample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Java</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix" ></div>
              
              <div class="code tab-content">
                  <pre id="phpsample" class="tab-pane active">
$email = "test@example.com";
$url = https://lesdsdsddsdssddsssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshub.com/api/verifyEmail?email=$email 
$key = "&lt;API Key&gt;";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get($url, 
  array(
  'headers'=> Bearer $key
  )
  );
  echo json_decode($response->getBody());
                  
                  

                  </pre>
                  <pre id="curlsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  




</pre>
<pre id="pythonsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddail?email=test@example.com
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
        


</pre>
<pre id="rubysample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://lesdddddddddddddddddddddb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            


</pre>
<pre id="javasample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://ldsfdsfsdfsdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
  
 </pre>
                  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well apply `overflow` to the `pre` elements then?

Comment: It's because you have placed the element inside an absolutely positioned element that has no width - this means that absolute element will just stretch to fit it's content which is causing the overflow on your document

Answer (score 1):

Just add a max-width and overflow to the `<pre>` tag.

```css
.container-full {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.top-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-header img {
    height: 83vh;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.header-content {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.header-content h1, p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.header-content h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.main-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 40px 8px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    color: #000;
}
.main-btn:hover {
    background: #c86bd6;
}
.btn-text {
    color: #f1020d;
}
.content-inner {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
/* CODE EXAMPLE */
.code-eg-container {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.code-eg-inner {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 410px;
    background: #22015473;
    padding: 13px;
}
.code-eg-header {
    display: block;
}
.code-eg-header a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.tab-pane {
    background: rgba(108,6,166,0.4);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(108,6,166,0.7) 6%, rgba(25,1,153,0.6) 100%);
    border: 0;
}
pre {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 90vw;
    overflow: auto;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-pills li a {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
display: inline-block;
line-height: normal;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 7px 21px 6px 21px;;
text-decoration: none;
background: transparent;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
transition: 0.2s linear;
font-weight: bold;
}

.code-eg-header .nav-pills li.active a {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44 !important;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
}
/* END */

/* MEDIA */
@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .code-eg-container {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .code-eg-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-full">
  <div class="top-header" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  </div>
  <div class="header-wrap">

    <div class="row header-content">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
          </p>
          <a class="main-btn">Let's Try <span class="btn-text">It's Free</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 code-eg-container">

            <div class="code-eg-inner">
              <div class="code-eg-header">
                <ul class="nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">PHP</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#curlsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Curl</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Python</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#rubysample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Ruby</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#javasample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Java</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix" ></div>
              
              <div class="code tab-content">
                  <pre id="phpsample" class="tab-pane active">
$email = "test@example.com";
$url = https://lesdsdsddsdssddsssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshub.com/api/verifyEmail?email=$email 
$key = "&lt;API Key&gt;";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get($url, 
  array(
  'headers'=> Bearer $key
  )
  );
  echo json_decode($response->getBody());
                  
                  

                  </pre>
                  <pre id="curlsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  




</pre>
<pre id="pythonsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddail?email=test@example.com
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
        


</pre>
<pre id="rubysample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://lesdddddddddddddddddddddb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            


</pre>
<pre id="javasample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://ldsfdsfsdfsdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
  
 </pre>
                  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also force the `<pre>` tag to break by using:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
```

```css
.container-full {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.top-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-header img {
    height: 83vh;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.header-content {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.header-content h1, p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.header-content h1 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.main-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 40px 8px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    color: #000;
}
.main-btn:hover {
    background: #c86bd6;
}
.btn-text {
    color: #f1020d;
}
.content-inner {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
/* CODE EXAMPLE */
.code-eg-container {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.code-eg-inner {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 410px;
    background: #22015473;
    padding: 13px;
}
.code-eg-header {
    display: block;
}
.code-eg-header a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.tab-pane {
    background: rgba(108,6,166,0.4);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(108,6,166,0.7) 6%, rgba(25,1,153,0.6) 100%);
    border: 0;
}
pre {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-pills li a {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
display: inline-block;
line-height: normal;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 7px 21px 6px 21px;;
text-decoration: none;
background: transparent;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
transition: 0.2s linear;
font-weight: bold;
}

.code-eg-header .nav-pills li.active a {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #61bc44 !important;
line-height: normal;
border: 0 !important;
}
/* END */

/* MEDIA */
@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .code-eg-container {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .code-eg-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-full">
  <div class="top-header" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  </div>
  <div class="header-wrap">

    <div class="row header-content">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-inner">
          <p>
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
          </p>
          <a class="main-btn">Let's Try <span class="btn-text">It's Free</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 code-eg-container">

            <div class="code-eg-inner">
              <div class="code-eg-header">
                <ul class="nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">PHP</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#curlsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Curl</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Python</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#rubysample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Ruby</a></li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="#javasample" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Java</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix" ></div>
              
              <div class="code tab-content">
                  <pre id="phpsample" class="tab-pane active">
$email = "test@example.com";
$url = https://lesdsdsddsdssddsssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshub.com/api/verifyEmail?email=$email 
$key = "&lt;API Key&gt;";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get($url, 
  array(
  'headers'=> Bearer $key
  )
  );
  echo json_decode($response->getBody());
                  
                  

                  </pre>
                  <pre id="curlsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  




</pre>
<pre id="pythonsample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://leb.com/api/verifyEmdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddail?email=test@example.com
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
        


</pre>
<pre id="rubysample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://lesdddddddddddddddddddddb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            


</pre>
<pre id="javasample" class="tab-pane">
curl -X GET --header "Authorization:Bearer &lt;API Key&gt;" 
https://ldsfdsfsdfsdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssb.com/api/verifyEmail?email=test@example.com
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
  
 </pre>
                  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```